# External SSO with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on an application which requires an integration of a proprietary SSO with spring security. The application uses spring boot, and the requirement is that we use the authentication from internal proprietary SSO module and authorization from the existing application. The existing application's authentication system has to be replaced with internal proprietary SSO's authentication module. I went through a few documents and understood that it is possible as the spring is module based.

While working on the application I noticed that we are using FilterRegistrationBean to initialize one filter, and another filter is added to the chain via WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's configure(HttpSecurity http) method.

Can someone please let me know if this will be treated as two different chains? If so, how are the chains checked for filtering out the details?

Can I just remove the filter we are adding via WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter's configure(HttpSecurity http) method and replace the existing filter that is registered via FilterRegistrationBean with the filter (with highest precedence) from internal proprietary SSO?

Answer (score 0):

OK so we do exactly what you're asking for in one of our systems. We have this working in Spring boot 1 and 2. These are the steps to take.

Create a bean extending `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`. Implement `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal` and `getPreAuthenticatedCredentials` to extract the authenticated user and optional credentials (e.g. a certificate) from your SSO system. Create a `FilterRegistrationBean` for this filter bean otherwise thanks to spring boot's component scanning it'll end up in the main filter chain as well as the security filter chain.

Create a user details (authorization) service bean implementing `AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>`. Override `loadUserDetails` to take your authenticated token and use it to add permissions in the form of `GrantedAuthority` lists.

In your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` bean subclass do the following:

1. Inject your subclass of `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and also your subclass of `AuthenticationUserDetailsService`.
2. Add a class member of type `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` and initialise it with `new` (it's not a bean).
3. In `configure(HttpSecurity)` initialise your filter bean with an authentication manager: `yourBean.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager())` then ensure your filter is included:

```
http.addFilter(yourBean)
  .authorizeRequests()
    .requestMatchers(...)
```

4. Override `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` and initialise the `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` you created in step (2) with your implementation of the authentication and authorization beans.

```
    this.preAuthProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(this.userDetailsService);
    this.preAuthProvider.setThrowExceptionWhenTokenRejected(true);

    authBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.preAuthProvider);
```

That should be all. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks much, Andy. This is very useful info. I shall give it a try.

Comment: Andy, In our case, we have an authentication filter from the sso client. That takes care of redirection and populates the required principal details. Will we still need AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter? Can't we just pass in the sso client's filter into web security config?

Comment: I don't think you can. The pre-authenticated filter relies on the work of authentication being done (by your SSO filter) and the HTTP servlet object being populated with the result (e.g. a cookie in our case). You should probably insert the preauthenticated filter _after_ your SSO filter in the chain, look for the results of the SSO login, validate it using whatever API they provide and then setup the principal/credentials as detailed above. FYI our SSO provider is ClearTrust.

Comment: Thank you very much, Andy. This is all very good and useful info. I shall try building a POC and see how it works! Thanks again!